# rethinkdb install on mint rebecca Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, rethinkdb, linux-mint

I want to install RethinkDB on mint rebecca
but when I run

```
source /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list
wget -qO- http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

I've got

```
W: Failed to fetch http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/dists/rebecca/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
```

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: Hey @Whisher, RethinkDB just rolled back to 2.1.4 from 2.1.5 this morning and you may have experienced some wonkiness. Try again and report back!

Comment: @dalanmiller it still doesn't work :(

Comment: looks like the answer below should get you there? Comment below if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "deb http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list
wget -qO- http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rethinkdb
```

[Source](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/mint/)